# Why is my static stack not working?

Tags: c, stack

## static stack implementation

> this is also not deleting according to the lifo principle
>
> static stack implementation:
> it is not taking name for the second time
> this is the new code now tell me why is it not working
> please help

```
typedef struct student {
    char name[20];
    int roll;
    int age;
} mystruct;

#define size 40
int top;
static mystruct s[size];
void push()
{
    if (top == size - 1) {
        printf("\noverflow");    //
    } else {
        printf("\nenter the name of the student");
        gets(s[top].name);//not taking name for d 2 time
        printf("\nenter the roll number");
        scanf("%d", &s[top].roll);
        printf("\nenter the age of the student");
        scanf("%d", &s[top].age);
        ++top;
    }
}
void pop()
{
    if (top == -1)
    
    {
        printf("\nunderflow");
    } else {
        printf("%s", s[top].name);
        printf("%d", s[top].roll);
        printf("%d", s[top].age);
        printf("\npopped");
        --top;
    }
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    
    if (top == -1) {
        printf("\nstack is empty");
    } else {
        for (i = top; i > 0; i--) {
            printf("\nthe name of the student is%s", s[top].name);
        }
        printf("\nthe roll no of the student is%d", s[top].roll);
        printf("\nthe age of the student is%d", s[top].age);
    }
    
}
main()
{

    top = -1;
    char ch;
    while (1) {
        printf("\nwelcome to static stack menu");
        printf("\n1.PUSH\n2.POP\n3.DISPLAY\n0.EXIT");
        printf("\nplease enter your choice\n");
        ch = getche();
        
        if (ch == '0') {
            break;
        }
        switch (ch) {
            case '1':
                push();
                break;
            case '2':
                pop();
                break;
            case '3':
                display();
                break;
            default:
                printf("choice not valid");
                break;
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Format your code correctly.

Comment: ch=getche(); must be ch=getchar();

Comment: why not getche what is the difference

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code in a more or less orthodox manner.  That means that the body of the functions is indented, and the body of the `if` and `while` statements is indented more, and the indentation is systematic.  When copying code into a question or answer, make sure it has no tabs (they wreck the layout on SO), and generally indent by 4 spaces per level (though you'll find code with indents of 2, 3, 4, or 8).  Copy the code into the edit box and make sure it looks correct in the edit box, then highlight it, and indent with the **`{}`** button above the edit box.

Comment: The `getche()` and `getch()` functions are declared in `<conio.h>` on Windows only.  They don't exist on other platforms (neither the functions nor the header exists).

Comment: we need minimal code which reproduces the **problem**. 99% of the code here is not relevant. if you have problems handling input, write a 5-10 line program which demonstrates it.

Comment: Why don't you add `printf("ch = %d = '%c'\n", ch, ch);` after you read the value with `getche()`?  This will tell you what your program is getting as a character, and may well tell you why it is not working.  Please don't SHOUT; it is rude.  Please look at the way I had your question formatted, and then re-edit to incorporate what you need from your edit into the framework I gave.  Or use one of the other edits.

Comment: One major problem is that you don't have a static stack; you have a local variable in `push()` and another (uninitialized) local variable in `pop()` that are completely unrelated to each other and neither of which lasts longer than the function call.  You need to move the declaration of `s` outside those two functions (`static mystack s[size];` next to `top`).  The `display()` function also needs to access `s` instead of `x`.  However, that has nothing to do with why the prompting and input is not working.

Comment: @user3371423: Formating code: read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Comment: it is not taking name for the second time

Comment: and also not deleting according to lifo structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I noticed was that `top` is initialized to `-1`. Trying to access the member data of `s[top]` when `top` is initialized to `-1` will result in unpredictable behavior.

I would suggest changing the line

```
top = -1;
```

to

```
top = 0;
```

That changes the basic assumption you have made in `push`, `pop`, and `display` about when the stack is empty and when it is full. Instead of checking `if ( top == -1 )`, you have to now check `if (top == 0 )`. Instead of checking `if ( top == size - 1 )`, you have to now check `if ( top == size )`.

In `pop`, you have to use `top-1` instead of `top`.

The `for` loop in `display` is not scoped correctly. You need to use:

```
   for (i = top-1; i >= 0; i--) {
       printf("\nthe name of the student is %s", s[i].name);
       printf("\nthe roll no of the student is %d", s[i].roll);
       printf("\nthe age of the student is %d", s[i].age);
   }
```

Also, reading the options for the menu and reading the subsequent input is little bit tricky.

After you read the menu option, you have to make sure that you eat up all the input until the next newline. Otherwise, `gets()` will read everything after your menu option until the end of the line. If you typed `1` for the menu and then typed Return/Enter, the name will be automatically accepted as "\n". Hence, I suggest the lines:

```
   printf("\nwelcome to static stack menu");
   printf("\n1.PUSH\n2.POP\n3.DISPLAY\n0.EXIT");
   printf("\nplease enter your choice\n");
   ch = fgetc(stdin);

   /* Skip till the end of line is read. */
   while ( fgetc(stdin) != '\n' );
```

Also, after you read the age of the object, you have to eat everything up to the newline. Otherwise, the newline character is read in as the choice for the next menu option.

```
    scanf("%d", &s[top].age);
    /* Skip till the end of line is read. */
    while ( fgetc(stdin) != '\n' );
```

Here's the fully working file. I have replaced `gets` by `fgets` and `getche` by `fgetc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    char name[20];
    int roll;
    int age;
} mystruct;

#define size 40
int top;
static mystruct s[size];
void push()
{
    if (top == size) {
        printf("\noverflow");    //
    } else {
        printf("\nenter the name of the student: ");
        fgets(s[top].name, 20, stdin);//not taking name for d 2 time
        // The newline character is part of s[top].name when fgets is
        // finished. Remove that.
        s[top].name[strlen(s[top].name)-1] = '\0';
        printf("\nenter the roll number: ");
        scanf("%d", &s[top].roll);
        printf("\nenter the age of the student: ");
        scanf("%d", &s[top].age);
        /* Skip till the end of line is read. */
        while ( fgetc(stdin) != '\n' );

        ++top;
    }
}
void pop()
{
    if (top == 0)
    {
        printf("\nunderflow");
    } else {
        printf("%s, ", s[top-1].name);
        printf("%d, ", s[top-1].roll);
        printf("%d", s[top-1].age);
        printf("\npopped");
        --top;
    }
}
void display()
{
   int i;

   if (top == 0) {
       printf("\nstack is empty");
   } else {
       for (i = top-1; i >= 0; i--) {
           printf("\nthe name of the student is %s", s[i].name);
           printf("\nthe roll no of the student is %d", s[i].roll);
           printf("\nthe age of the student is %d", s[i].age);
       }
   }

}

main()
{

   top = 0;
   char ch;
   while (1) {
       printf("\nwelcome to static stack menu");
       printf("\n1.PUSH\n2.POP\n3.DISPLAY\n0.EXIT");
       printf("\nplease enter your choice\n");
       ch = fgetc(stdin);

       /* Skip till the end of line is read. */
       while ( fgetc(stdin) != '\n' );

       if (ch == '0') {
           break;
       }
       switch (ch) {
           case '1':
              push();
              break;
           case '2':
              pop();
              break;
           case '3':
              display();
              break;
           default:
              printf("choice, %c, not valid", ch);
              break;
       }    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `getche()` to `getchar()`

Note: `getche()` is a non-standard function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_385.html 
Pay attention to implementation note:
"If you can detect the situation when one of the conio functions is called for the very    first time since program start, you could work around this problem by calling the gppconio_init function manually"
or just replace it with getchar(). And there meaned conio included.